# How can I display JWT bearer token roles required for endpoint in swagger UI for asp.net core 6 api endpoints

Tags: asp.net-core, jwt, swagger, roles, display

I have an asp.net core 5/6 api with endpoints protected by roles using JWT Bearer Auth

I would like show in the swagger UI, what roles are supported by each of those endpoints.
Kindly advice how I can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have controllers or APIs decorated with Authorize attribute along with roles like

[image: controller level authorize attribute]

or

[image: API level authorize attribute]

although there is no separate place in swagger doc to show these information but we can enhance summary or description of a path in swagger doc to show this.

for that we have to add an custom OperationFilter like below

```
public class MyCustomOperationFilter : IOperationFilter
{
    public void Apply(OpenApiOperation operation, OperationFilterContext context)
    {
        // get roles at method level first.
        var roles = context.MethodInfo.
             GetCustomAttributes(true)
             .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
             .Select(a => a.Roles)
             .Distinct()
             .ToArray();

        // we dont find roles at method level then check for controller level.
        if(!roles.Any())
        {
           roles = context.MethodInfo.DeclaringType?
                .GetCustomAttributes(true)
                .OfType<AuthorizeAttribute>()
                .Select(attr => attr.Roles)
                .Distinct()
                .ToArray();
        }
        
        if (roles.Any())
        {
            string rolesStr = string.Join(",", roles);
            // we can choose summary or description as per our preference
            operation.Description += $"<p> Required Roles ({rolesStr})</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

with these changes we can see the role info for each API like below

[image: Role info shown in swagger ui]

[image: role info at api level]

Currently this limited to show role info only from authorize attribute.